# BigQuery load job does not insert all data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have about 200k CSVs(all with same schema). I wrote a Cloud Function for them to insert them to BigQuery such that as soon as I copy the CSV to a bucket, the function is executed and data is loaded to the BigQuery dataset

I basically used the same code as in the documentation.

```
dataset_id = 'my_dataset'  # replace with your dataset ID
table_id = 'my_table'  # replace with your table ID
table_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)
table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)  # API request 

def bigquery_csv(data, context):

  job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
  job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
  job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
  # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
  job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV

  uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(data['bucket'], data['name'])
  errors = bigquery_client.load_table_from_uri(uri,
                                    table_ref,
                                    job_config=job_config)  # API request

  logging.info(errors)
  #print('Starting job {}'.format(load_job.job_id))

  # load_job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
  logging.info('Job finished.')

  destination_table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)
  logging.info('Loaded {} rows.'.format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

However, when I copied all the CSVs to the bucket(which were about 43 TB), not all data was added to BigQuery and only about 500 GB was inserted.

I can't figure what's wrong. No insert jobs are being shown in Stackdriver Logging and no functions are running once the copy job is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, when I copied all the CSVs to the bucket(which were about 43 TB), not all data was added to BigQuery and only about 500 GB was inserted.

You are hitting BigQuery load limit as defined in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs)

[image]

You should split your file into smaller file and the upload will work

Comment: I assume that because there are about 200k files, then 200k functions would be triggered. Because 200k different functions would be triggered, they would count as separate load jobs. 43 TB is the size in total of all the CSVs. Otherwise, each CSV is around 300 MB.

Comment: Correct this is also a limit defined in the link I provided. Hope you have a way to throttle the load if not you can open another question on this topic. Appriciate for now if you can accept and vote up my answer. Best.

Comment: @PranayNanda, Thank you for accepting my answer also important to vote-up on SO as you already know. Appreciate if you can do this as well, Best.

Comment: Since you are loading a big amount of data, a quota is the most probable cause of your issue. I would like to add that if you don't reach the 'Maximum File Sizes' quota, you could be reaching the 'Row and cell size limits' or other. In any case, you can use the BigQuery job id to search it in your logs to figure out if the job failed to load the data.